# Can I leave butter cookies in the fridge?

Tags: storage-method, cookies

I've just baked a batch of chocolate butter cookies. They're nice an gooey, a couple of them so gooey that they fell apart, but I'm happy with the consistency for the most part. I'm bringing them into work tomorrow.

What's the best way to store them overnight for eating the next day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store them outside, not inside the fridge. Fridge temperatures make anything containing flour go stale quickly. Of course, sometimes people have to live with it, such as when they have made a cake with perishable icing or filling. But cookies are not perishable, so they are better stored outside of the fridge.

As to whether to put them in a sealed container or not, it depends on the cookie. The harder type does all right in the air, and can get flaccid in a sealed container. If they are soft, they are probably better off covered. It is still preferable to not isolate them completely, a canvas bag or a bread box with ventilation slits does better.

Answer (score 2):

Given there's chocolate and butter, if you put them in the fridge, they'll get a bit more compact, but will stay OK. They would also stay OK if left outside, but keep them in one of those hermetically closed recipients like Tupperware to prevent drying. Anyway, one day is not a lot in the lifetime of a cookie :)

Comment: Not a lot? These cookies aren't being eaten until tomorrow; that's remarkably long-lived! :)